# Dismissing a custom viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm currently using a third party called "Form".
In my `UIButton`, I implement a method which initializes a custom view controller which is a subclass of `FormViewController`. I initialize `FormViewController` embedded in navigation controller.

In my `FormViewController` class, I tried below two methods but none of them did not work.

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Codes for pressing a `UIButton`:

```
@IBAction func part1Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let JSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithContentsOfFile("data.JSON") as? [String : AnyObject] {
        let initialValues = [
                "last_name"  : "Nordman"]
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewContainerVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewContainerVC")
        let sampleController = Part1_VC(JSON: JSON, initialValues: initialValues)
        let rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sampleController)

        rootViewController.view.tintColor = UIColor(hex: "5182AF")
        rootViewController.navigationBarHidden = false

        FORMDefaultStyle.applyStyle()
        FORMSeparatorView.appearance().setSeparatorColor(UIColor.clearColor())

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to dismiss the view controller when it wasn't presented in the first place.

Instead set the root view controller of the navigation controller to something else (e.g. the screen you want shown after you dismiss the form) and present your form view controller modally:

```
self.presentViewController(formVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You can then dismiss the view controller as you intended when you are finished with the form.